# beanstalkd driver configuration error in laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I am trying to use `beanstalkd` as the queue driver for my laravel app. I am getting this error when I am trying to push something on the queue.

```
Pheanstalk_Exception_ConnectionException
Socket error 111: Connection refused (connecting to localhost:11300)
```

Please note that in '`queue.php`' I have just changed the default driver to '`beanstalkd`' but haven't changed any settings for the driver. The settings for the driver are as follows-

```
'beanstalkd' => array(
            'driver' => 'beanstalkd',
            'host'   => 'localhost',
            'queue'  => 'default',
        ),
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Figured it out. Did these two things -

```
$ sudo vim /etc/default/beanstalkd
> START yes     # uncomment

$ sudo service beanstalkd start
# Alternatively: /etc/init.d/beanstalkd start
```

Got it from this link - http://fideloper.com/ubuntu-beanstalkd-and-laravel4

Comment: Very glad that it helped :)

Comment: @halkujabra any an idea how to do it on Mac OS ?

Comment: Same error here, but /etc/default/beanstalkd doesn´t include this line anymore: > START yes     # uncomment      Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @halkujabra is correct. The error is because beanstalkd is not running. To fix it you just have to start beanstalkd. For MacOS use this script https://gist.github.com/finger-berlin/1942295 to to that.

- Download and save it as `script.sh`
- Make it executable: `chmod a+x script.sh`
- Run `./script.sh start`